# Edit a command send to background

Tags: linux, bash, background-process

Is it possible to edit the command line of a process sent to background, or to chain another command to execute after the first command has exited?

Eg:
I start mirroring a site with `wget -m site.com` but later realize that I want to be notified by email when the job executed. The job is running in the background (`bg`). How can I add a `&& sendmail` to the command, or execute it when the first command has completed execution?

Answer (score 2):

If you've still got the session you started the original command from and you just want to know when it finishes then you can use `wait` which will wait until the specified child process completes. Assuming the use of `bash` something like ...

```
$ ./30s &
[1] 32135

$ wait %1 && echo hello
[1]+  Done                    ./30s
hello
```

... replacing the `echo` command with a more useful notification.

This doesn't get you any of the output from the original command but gives a simple way to notify on completion.

If you don't still have the session you started the original command from then you'd need to knock together a script to watch for the process disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no any built in way to do this. However I'd run just a oneliner to achieve what you need.

However you need to know your process id of the bg process (in your case `wget`). You could run `ps aux | grep wget`

Once you have the PID, You can use `wait` . However this doesn't work if you closed the previous shell or session.

In that case I'd use `ps -p PID` with a `while` loop to fire sleeps while the process is active and after process stopped `while` statement ends and shell will execute your `sendmail` command.

Full code goes as:

```
while ps -p YOUR-PID > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done && echo "Subject: WGET DONE!" | sendmail user@domain.com
```

summery of above code: while your selected PID process runs `while` condition becomes true and loop keeps executing `sleep 1` and it checks for it's condition every one second. However if the process ends `while` condition becomes false and the while loop will end. And the shell will execute the command after && which is `sendmail`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You could try to attach a debugger (strace, gdb) and get your output that way and then mail that information.
But first you'd get a different output format and second this is all kinds of things but not very useful.